# Upgrading Windows 7 using serial port keyboard and mouse

Tags: windows-7

I am upgrading my Windows Home premium software to windows 10 on my current hard drive and putting it into a new case. The issue I am having is that the windows 10 software will not recognize the serial port peripherals. I am having trouble finding drivers to do this. I have a USB keyboard and wireless mouse to install once the upgrade is completed in a new PC. But the techs are saying I need to wipe my hard drive and do a fresh install first and I don't want to lose all my data. Is there a way around this?

Comment: What is a serial port peripheral? Serial ports are rarely used anymore, most computers don’t even have them, and the last time a mouse used a serial port was probably like the 1990’s and I’ve never seen a keyboard use a serial port.

Comment: @Appleoddity -- Agree that the question is confusing, but you're not helping. *"most computers don’t even have them"*  --  You're conflating PCs with all computers.  Single board computers, SBCs, and embedded systems typically have a serial port for a system console.  Industrial systems still use RS-232 and its variants.

Comment: If you're actually using a USB keyboard, then call it  that instead of *"serial keyboard"*.  Do not conflate USB with *"serial"* ports.  Do you also call a SATA disk a *"serial disk"* to be consistent?

Comment: Windows allows you to install drivers before the installation. However, you should also check your BIOS settings. BIOS often have options to enabled USB mice and keyboards before the OS picks them up, and this may need to be enabled.

Comment: Use sysprep built into W7 (assuming that is the OS that is current) to prepare the system to be moved to new hardware, then move the drive to the new pc and boot into W7, then upgrade to 10.....https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/135077-windows-7-installation-transfer-new-computer.html